# If God had a bachelor's degree

Tags: theology

stupid question... but what do you think it would be?

at first I thought business/management (ceo of the universe), but then I thought
an engineer would be more appropiate (creator of an automated system - and now can't do anything about it).
but then I thought the best one would be music. (he's like a conductor and the universe is his composition).

Comment: CEO of the Universe, LOL

Comment: This does not feel like a particularly urgent or important concern as currently formulated. Is there any chance you can share a little more about why this has become a *serious and interesting* problem, encountered during your study of philosophy? What have you been reading that might help contextualize and motivate this; and what exactly would you like someone here to *explain* to you?

Comment: He would be an intelligent designer MWAHAHAHAHA

Answer (score 1):

Philosophy--because none of it makes any sense.

Comment: there is no place for a monotheistic God in the academia: who would peer review his papers? :)

Comment: Usually God is said to be omniscient,  so I don't think he needs to learn philosophy :) And @DzmitryTsapkou, you can have a degree without publishing any papers.